# Error loading Qt applications on Windows when compiled with Qt 5.2 static libraries

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've successfully built Qt 5.2 as **static** but, once I run an application using that libraries, I get the following runtime error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows".

I would like to know if there is a way to **avoid DLL dependencies** to have standalone .exe files. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just some probably useful info: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23705, http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56285-Failed-to-load-platform-plugin-quot-windows-quot

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, that links don't help me since I am looking for the "static" way, this is avoid using DLLs.

Comment: In case this is a closed source program - the LGPL license permits only dynamics linking for closed source programs.

Comment: Not my case, is for an open source application. So, is there a way to avoid using DLLs?

Comment: @sashoalm: This is not correct.

Comment: The only solution I've found so far is to modify Qt build to use the statically linked-in platform plugin. It did require changes to the build scripts and some patches to Qt. I'm not using it in production yet.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Folder named "platforms" in your Application folder and put the qwindows.dll in it.
That'll fix the problem.

With the QT Source Code you can.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The point is that I would like to avoid including folders and DLLs.